# Numpy concatenate behaviour. How to concatenate example correctly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following multi-dimensional array:

```
windows = array([[[[[[0., 0.],
           [1., 0.]],

          [[0., 0.],
           [1., 0.]],

          [[0., 0.],
           [1., 0.]]],


         [[[0., 1.],
           [0., 0.]],

          [[0., 1.],
           [0., 0.]],

          [[1., 0.],
           [0., 0.]]],


         [[[1., 0.],
           [0., 0.]],

          [[0., 1.],
           [0., 0.]],

          [[0., 1.],
           [0., 0.]]]]]])
print(windows.shape)
(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2) # (n, d, a, b, c, c) w = a * (c*c), h = b * (c*c)
```

I want to get next resulting array:

```
mask = array([[
        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]] 
]], dtype=np.float32)
print(mask.shape)
(1, 1, 6, 6) # (n, d, w, h)
```

Basically, I want to squeeze last 4 dimensions into 2-d matrix so the final shape become (n, d, w, h), in this case (1, 1, 6, 6).

I tried `np.concatenate(windows, axis = 2)`, but it didnt concatenate along 2nd dimension and reduced for some reason first(although I set axis = 2) 'n' dimension.

Additional information: 
windows is a result of following code snippet

```
windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr, (c, c), axis (-2,-1), writeable = True) # arr.shape == mask.shape
windows = windows[:, :, ::c, ::c] # these are non-overlapping windows of arr with size (c,c)
windows = ... # some modifications of windows
```

Now I want to build from these windows array with shape of `arr.shape`, this array called `mask` in example above. Simple reshape doesn't work because it returns elements in wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to merge dimensions 2+4 and 3+5, an easy way would be to [`swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) 4 and 5 (or -3 and -2), and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to (1,1,6,6):

```
windows.swapaxes(-2,-3).reshape(1,1,6,6)
```

output:

```
array([[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]])
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But anyway, why simple np.concatenate(windows, axis = *any axis*) reduces the first axis and not merging the one I set?

Comment: Probably related to calling [np.concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with just 1 array. That might cause it to flatten the array.

Comment: Yes, concatenate is used to merge several arrays on one common dimension

Comment: Oh, I see. But why then there's no function in numpy to merge arrays along certain axis of ndarray?

Comment: `reshape` does merge axes - adjacent ones.  `concatenate`  treats 1 argument as a sequence arrays, splitting on the first.  It's intended for joining arrays, not reordering or reshaping one.